# Keypad won't show

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a lot of trouble with the keypad not showing up.

I have a simple layout with all number EditText views - but (a) no keypad shows up for the first EditText field and then only the alpha pad shows up for the remaining ones. Is this a bug.

Here's the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lbBOS_previous"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
          android:paddingBottom="10dip"
          android:text="@string/empties_bos_before"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/etBOS_previous"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="right" 
         android:enabled="false"
         android:focusable="false"
          android:ems="10"
          android:inputType="number" >


      </EditText>

   </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lbBottleSales"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
          android:paddingBottom="10dip"
          android:text="@string/empties_bottleSales"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/etBottlesBought"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="right" 
         android:enabled="false"
         android:focusable="false"
          android:ems="10"
          android:inputType="number" >


      </EditText>

   </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/lbEmpties"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                 android:layout_width="200dp"
                 android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                 android:text="@string/empties_pickup"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/etEmptiesPU"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" 
                 android:layout_weight="1"

                 android:ems="10"
                 android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
             </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/lbBOS_after"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                   android:text="@string/empties_bos_after"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/etBOSAfter"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" 
                   android:layout_weight="1"

                   android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" >


               </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/lbCoolers"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                   android:text="@string/empties_coolers"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/etCoolersPU"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" 
                   android:layout_weight="1"

                   android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" >


               </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/lbracks"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                   android:text="@string/empties_racks"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/etRacksPU"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" 
                   android:layout_weight="1"

                   android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" >


               </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/lbemptiesWarning"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                   android:text="@string/empties_saveWarning"
                   android:textSize="10sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>




         <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/cmdDoneEmpties"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"

                 android:text="@string/cmd_done" />


    </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `android:enabled` to false one the first two EditText's, and on the other ones you have explicitly asked it to only show the numberpad, by specifying `android:inputType="number"`. So the behavior is totally correct.

**Edit:** Ahh sorry misread your question a bit. To actually have the number pad showing up you have to target Android 1.5 and up. You should also be able to limit what characters are shown by doing something like this:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="1234567890"
    ...
/>
```